# How can I add a scroll delay during autoplay with react-native-reanimated-carousel

Tags: javascript, react-native, carousel

I am using react native reanimated carousel. What I intend is to extend the time spent viewing each rendered item before scrolling to the next item. Like an autoplay delay. Here is the code:

```
  <Carousel
            loop
            width={width}
            data={data}
            scrollAnimationDuration={1000}
            autoPlay={true}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => {
              const {title, desc, image: Image, style} = item;
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}>
                  <Image height={height / 3} style={style} />
                  <Text
                    style={[
                      styles.textCenter,
                      styles.whiteColor,
                      {fontSize: 24, marginTop: 20, fontWeight: '900'},
                    ]}>
                    {title}
                  </Text>
                  <Text
                    style={[
                      styles.textCenter,
                      styles.whiteColor,
                      styles.font12,
                      styles.p20,
                      {maxWidth: 350, alignSelf: 'center', lineHeight: 18},
                    ]}>
                    {desc}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
```

Here is the output, the current display duration is about 1 second. I would like to extend it to 3 seconds or so.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I eventually worked it out. The prop is stated in the library documentation here https://reanimated-carousel.dev/props#autoplayinterval

```
autoPlayInterval={4000}
```